# Why Is My Main Controller Being Called Twice?

Tags: sapui5

All other routings are fine, but for some reason the main controller is being called twice. Why would this happen?

```js
onInit: function() {
  var oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
  oRouter.getRoute("main").attachMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
  this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel({
    Jobs: []
  }), "job");
},
```

Is this down to the routing config?

```json
"rootView": {
  "viewName": "CompleteSurvey.view.Main",
  "type": "XML"
},
"routing": {
  "routes": [{
    "name": "main",
    "pattern": "",
    "target": ["main"]
  }],
  "config": {
    "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
    "viewType": "XML",
    "viewPath": "CompleteSurvey.view",
    "controlId": "app",
    "controlAggregation": "pages"
  },
  "targets": {
    "main": {
      "viewName": "Main"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why your `Main` controller is created twice is because its view is created twice.

1. Your Component fetches *manifest.json* and looks at the `rootView` to create the assigned view (`"CompleteSurvey.view.Main"`).
2. Your router gets initialized, sees that the current hash / pattern is `""`, and creates the corresponding view which is the `"Main"` view again.

The current best practice is to have a separate root view. You can keep the `Main` for the `""` pattern, but avoid using the same view again as a root view.

---

For further references, take a look at the tutorial *[Navigation and Routing](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d)* and [this answer](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1746#issuecomment-346808328).

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer. Has helped me a lot.